# Backbone view Events not binding to multiple template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, handlebars.js, backbone-events

In my Backbone view, I have my main view being rendered using the Backbone render function.

```
            this.setElement($(".prodDetailContainer"));
            this.$el.html(this.templateDesktop(this.dataSet.toJSON()));
```

`this` refers to the backbone view here. I'm setting the `el` to the class where the complied template needs to be attached. When the view completely renders, the Events are attached fine to this rendered template.

My issue is I'm also rendering other templates in a separate function in the BB view as

```
$(".attachDetails").html(this.prodDetailsTemplate(selAgg.toJSON()));
```

Now, for this above `prodDetailsTemplate`, I'm unable attach any Events using
BB events

```
 events: {
  "click .future-inv" : "changeGlyfIcon"                
 },
```

The class `future-inv` lies inside the `prodDetailsTemplate`. Only if I use the backbone `el`, the events are getting registered. Is there any way to have the events attached to both the templates?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is the `.attachDetails` element a descendant of the `'.prodDetailsContainer` element?

Comment: @76484, No its not a descendant of that element. If I do this , `this.setElement($(".attachDetails"));` and render the that template, now I can attach the events to this template and doesn't work for the other template. It looks like Events only bind to the 'el'. What options do I have here to make this work for both?

Comment: Create a new View constructor for "attachDetails" and put the events on that object.

Comment: @76484, Thanks mate. I did the same thing just now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the sentence 
    `$(".attachDetails .future-inv").click(changeGlyfIcon);`
after
    `$(".attachDetails").html(this.prodDetailsTemplate(selAgg.toJSON()));`

Check if that works??